# How to split a menu within a wagtail model?

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to create a navigation menu, that when the number of objects within the menu is even puts an image between the two halves of the menu. Here is the code that I tried to use within my menu model and templates to create the effect.

```
"""Splitting the menu in half for the frontend."""
    @property
    def is_even(self):
        if (self.objects.count() % 2) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    @property
    def find_halves(self):
        first_half = self.objects[0:self.objects.count()/2]
        second_half = self.objects[self.objects.count()/2:self.objects.count()]
        return first_half, second_half
```

```
    <nav class="main-nav">

        {% image navigation.logo fill-115x115 as logo %}
            
        <ul class="nav-links">
        {% if navigation.is_even %}
            {% for item in navigation.menu_items.first_half.all %}
            <li><a href="{{ item.link }}" {% if item.open_in_new_tab %} target="_blank" {% endif %}>{{ item.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            <img src="{{ logo.url }}" alt="CCCR Logo" class="logo"> 
            {% for item in navigation.menu_items.second_half.all %} 
            <li><a href="{{ item.link }}" {% if item.open_in_new_tab %} target="_blank" {% endif %}>{{ item.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %} 
        {% else %}
            <img src="{{ logo.url }}" alt="CCCR Logo" class="logo"> 
            {% for item in navigation.menu_items.all %}
            <li><a href="{{ item.link }}" {% if item.open_in_new_tab %} target="_blank" {% endif %}>{{ item.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %} 
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

However, when I run the code it goes to the else statement even though I have six menu items in the wagtail admin.

Comment: The logic inside `is_even` looks correct, so I think we need to see more of the model code to be able to debug this. Where does the `navigation` variable in the template come from? Is that definitely the same object where `is_even` and `find_halves` are defined? If so, where does `navigation.menu_items` come from, and is that different to the `self.objects` you're using in the model code? Are you actually calling `find_halves` anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an item like this that is related to what users see, I would suggest using the Django template tag `divisibleby`:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby

So maybe something like this:

`{% if navigation.menu_items.count|divisibleby:"2" %}`

You might also find the `cycle` template tag useful.  It might let you do what you want layout-wise by alternating the placement of a class on odd and even items.

Comment: Okay, I'll be sure to add that instead of the is_even property. Do you have any suggestion for splitting my menu into two parts? Should I do this within the template or the model for the snippet?

Comment: I would do it in the template.  That's why I suggested using a template tag rather than creating view-specific functions on the model.  Also, I've updated the answer with another template tag suggestion.